# ion-label is not displaying whole text in Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using ion-label inside ion-item, but the description is not displaying (instead it shows dot-dot.. ..) I want it to display whole text.. Is there any solution?

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let product of products">
    <img [src]="product.imageURL" />
    <ion-card-content>
        <ion-card-title primary [innerHTML]="product.title"></ion-card-title>
        <ion-item class="item-text-wrap">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label primary>Description</ion-label>
            <ion-label [innerHTML]="product.description"></ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You can also set the `text-wrap` attribute in the `ion-card` like this

```
<ion-card text-wrap *ngFor="let product of products">
...
</ion-card>
```

*Bonus tip*: If you put `text-wrap` (as an attribute, not as a class) in an `ion-list`, all items in that list will have the `text-wrap` effect applied. This way you don't need to put the `text-wrap` attribute in all items and this will help you making your app slightly optimized.

---

**Old answer:**

You can use a `ion-textarea` (disabled) to show the description. Find more information about the ion-textarea element [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/input/TextArea/).

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let product of products">
    <img [src]="product.imageURL" />
    <ion-card-content>
        <ion-card-title primary>{{ product.title }}</ion-card-title>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label primary>Description</ion-label>
            <ion-textarea rows="6" disabled [value]="product.description"></ion-textarea>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

The `rows` attribute allows you to set how many rows do you want to show, according to how long the text of the description is. By using the `disable` attribute, the `ion-textarea` is similar to a `label`, but showing more than  one line of content. And last but not least, I use the `value` attribute to set the content of the element with the product's description.

A few comments about your code:

1. You're opening two `ion-item` elements, but closing only one of them

   ```
   <ion-item class="item-text-wrap">
           <ion-item>
           <!-- ... -->
   </ion-item>
   ```
2. Instead of using the `[innerHTML]` attribute binding with the product title, you can just use interpolation

   ```
   <ion-card-title primary>{{ product.title }}</ion-card-title>
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Useful Suggestions.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: `[innerHtml]` is useful if you have html content to display. Very unlikely for the product.title though.

Answer (score 0):

For me the goal with **IONIC 3.x** was to put the flag primary:

```
<ion-label primary>collection response: {{ this.response }} </ion-label>
```